# Mysterious shared folder

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, samba

There is a mysterious folder being shared in an internal server with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

There is nothing pointing to that folder in the /etc/samba/smb.conf file. What happen was that this sharing configuration was made before I have access to that server and the person who made it curiously does not remember how did that.

How can I discover how was made that sharing?

Answer (score 0):

# To access your network share

```
  sudo apt-get install smbclient
  # List all shares:
  smbclient -L //<HOST_IP_OR_NAME>/<folder_name> -U <user>
  # connect:
  smbclient //<HOST_IP_OR_NAME>/<folder_name> -U <user>
```

To access your network share use your username `(<user_name>)` and password through the path` "smb:////" (Linux users) or "\\\" (Windows users). Note that "" value is passed in "[]", in other words, the share name you entered in "/etc/samba/smb.conf".

Note: The default user group of samba is "WORKGROUP".

i hope it might just do.

Comment: You helped a lot!

Bellow is the screenshot of the output from this command. The 'files' sharing is not in the /etc/samba/smb.conf file and I don't know where is this being configured. This is my real problem =S

https://i.ibb.co/h7y1SYv/lista-sharing-samba-lider.png

Answer (score 0):

Might as well put this out there in the event that someone else comes across it. I also had a mysterious samba share that was not listed in the `smb.conf`.

It turns out I had a symbolic link that was either shared before or pointed to a folder that was shared. Deleting the symlink got rid of the samba share after a `smbd` service restart. Restoring the symlink from the trash caused the samba share to come back. Very mysterious indeed.